# Layering many transparent images in browser

Tags: html

I'm currently creating an interactive anatomy app for learning purposes.

I'm starting with a spine module, which contains 24 vertebrae, a pelvis, skull and spinal cord.

Each piece is a separate transparent image of the same size, and each are layered top to bottom.

This works and looks great! The problem is, it is extremely processor intensive. Adding and removing little pieces, zooming in, almost any interaction at all is VERY slow.

Is there a way to layer all of those images in a performant manner? I would like for a student to be able to remove a lamina, and have that vertebrae swap out the image. Or to zoom in on only the Lumbar vertebrae and interact there.

What approach, technology, etc should I be looking at?

https://jsfiddle.net/whetw8o5/1/

```
Fiddle for reference.
```

Fiddle contains a transition tag for height, so you can easily use a tool and modify the height of the parent `#spineo` tag and see how much trouble it has.

Fiddle performs better than my site because it is by itself.

Comment: Putting together a jsFiddle and sharing some code here would be a good start.

Comment: @BenM Fiddle added. Fiddle runs a little better than the site it is in, which is a bootstrap site.

Comment: Although it look really nice, It's impossible (AFAIK) to know what's causing this piece of code to run slow, can you add a link to the website where it's actually run slow?

Comment: @AlonEitan Unfortunately, no, it is on an unpublished app right now. Have you tried altering the height and watching the animation? It still runs very slowly on my end.

Comment: @Wesley I did, and it worked perfectly fast. If you've included additional plugins on your page, you can deactivate each one and try to eliminate the possibility that an external plugin is causing this

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan, I will try that.

Comment: @AlonEitan Do you by chance have a VERY fast machine? Nice video card?

Comment: Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz * 4
Display: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
OS: Windows 10 64bit
16GB RAM

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks! I'll give others a chance to chime in before I go hunting for more.